# How to get the texture size in HLSL?

Tags: xna, textures, hlsl

For a HLSL shader I'm working on (for practice) I'm trying to execute a part of the code if the texture coordinates (on a model) are above half the respective size (that is `x > width / 2` or `y > height / 2`). I'm familiar with C/C++ and know the basics of HLSL (the very basics). If no other solution is possible, I will set the texture size manually with XNA (in which I'm using the shader, as a matter of fact). Is there a better solution? I'm trying to remain within Shader Model 2.0 if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default texture coordinate space is normalized to 0..1 so `x > width / 2` should simply be `texcoord.x > 0.5`.

Comment: Just to make sure - do you know if this is also true in unity? That is, the vertex.uv vector is a float2 with 0..1 entries?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful here. tex2d() and other texture calls should *NOT* be within if()/else clauses. So if you have a pixel shader input "IN.UV" and your aiming at "OUT.color," you need to do it this way:

```
float4 aboveCol = tex2d(mySampler,some_texcoords);
float4 belowCol = tex2d(mySampler,some_other_texcoords);
if (UV.x >= 0.5) {
   OUT.color = /* some function of... */ aboveCol;
} else {
   OUT.color = /* some function of... */ belowCol;
}
```

rather than putting teh tex() calls inside the if() blocks.

Comment: I see. Can you please tell me why is this like that?

Comment: Because the texture units work across neighboring pixels to correctly calculate the appropriate filter size/MIP level -- that is, they need to evaluate the UV variance in both screen-space X and Y (hence the presence of ddx() and ddy() functions in HLSL). if() statements have infinitely-high potential frequency. If you COULD put tex2D() inside an if() clause, then you would have texturing/filtering errors.